# Custom date in Einstein Analytics

Tags: tableau-api, crm, salesforce-einstein

I am new to Einstein Analytics/Tableau CRM.
I am trying to create a custom date filter (Toggle to select years - 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)
The default date filter in Einstein analytics has too many selections which are not relevant for my use case.

Appreciate your help.

Any thoughts or ideas please share, it would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

It’s common to filter based on a custom set of date ranges. To accomplish this, create a custom query with rows for each custom date range. You can specify ranges using absolute or relative dates.

```
[ 
    {label: "8/30/15 - 8/30/16", range: [[2015, 8, 30], [2016, 8, 30]]} 
    {label: "7/30/16 - 8/30/16", range: [[2016, 7, 30], [2016, 8, 30]]} 
]
```